# What is wrong with this JavaScript in my html file?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I made this HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <title>Don't Starve Drawings</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <center>
        <p>
            <script>
                function updateScript();{
                var wilson = document.getElementById("wilson");
                var willow = document.getElementById("willow");
                var mighty = document.getElementById("mighty");
                }
                window.addEventListener("click",function(event){

                    updateScript();
                    console.log(wilson+willow+mighty);
                });
            </script>
            <h1>
            <strong>
                Welcome!
            </strong>
        </h1>
            <h4>
            <strong>Website is still in Beta</strong>
        </h4>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input style="text" name="wilson" id="wilson" maxlength="1" size="1">Wilson Drawing
        </p>
        <p>
            <input style="text" name="willow" id="willow" maxlength="1" size="1">Willow Drawing
        </p>
        <p>
            <input style="text" name="mighty" id="mighty" maxlength="1" size="1">Mighty Drawing
        </p>
    </center>
</head>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

My problem is that the JavaScript console always prints:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

I know only basic JavaScript so I have no idea why this code is wrong. D:

What is the problem within my code???

Comment: `function updateScript();{`, remove the `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` means that you've put an extra semicolon somewhere you shouldn't have.

In this case, you have an extra semicolon after your function declaration. Instead of

```
 function updateScript();{
            var wilson = document.getElementById("wilson");
            var willow = document.getElementById("willow");
            var mighty = document.getElementById("mighty");
            }
```

You should use

```
 function updateScript() {
            var wilson = document.getElementById("wilson");
            var willow = document.getElementById("willow");
            var mighty = document.getElementById("mighty");
            }
```

Comment: Have to wait 9 minutes. :/

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the javascript: function `updateScript();{` remove the `;`